# How to fix problems with mouseup and mousedown?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that returns 'haha' when the user clicks up and down.  I am having trouble with the amount of times this gets retuned though.  The first time I click up/down, 'haha' only gets returned once.  The second time I go through this, it gets printed twice.  The third time, 'haha' gets printed 3 times and so on.  Any advice on why this is happening?  I only want 'haha' to be printed once for each up/down.

```
                $(".test").mousedown(function(){
                 $(".test").mouseup(function(){
                  console.log('haha');

                  });
                });
```

Comment: Why don't you use `click` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/), so that the event handling is unbound after the mouseup :

```
            $(".test").mousedown(function(){
             $(".test").one('mouseup', function(){
              console.log('haha');

              });
            });
```

But it seems simpler to simply use click :

```
$(".test").click(function(){ console.log('haha') });
```

Comment: funny workaround but it is not the solution for the basic problem, that the second-event-handler is just re-defined everytime you hit the first handler.. once is nice but should not be the solution for that... just code it right and it will work with the already written code ^^

Comment: @jebbie In fact, as I don't get the purpose of the strange OP's code, I really don't know what would be the right solution for the *real* problem.

Comment: Do you mean `one()`, not `once()`?

Comment: Thanks @Ian to always check my answer.

Comment: @dystroy i don't wanted to be philosophic in my answer - i really have no idea wat could be the _real_ problem behind this solution - for that, you have to know the original requirement...

Answer (score 2):

You're adding a new mouseup event handler every time you click mouse down. You may want to separate the two, or just use the mouseup handler.

Answer (score 1):

This is because each time the mousedown event is triggered, a new mouseup event is added to the target element.
Remove the mouseup event immediately again  on the firing of mouseup event and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your code you are adding the "mouseup" handler every time the user clicks.  You don't need to wait for the mousedown event in order to add this handler; you should just be able to add it from scratch.  If you really want to make sure the mousedown has been triggered first, use a boolean, like so:

```
var mouseClicked = false;

$(".test").mousedown(function(){
    mouseClicked = truel
}).mouseup(function(){
    if (mouseClicked ==true){
        console.log('haha');
    }
});
```